# Verification of a Diffeomorphism

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Below is an exercise to prepare for an Analysis II Exam

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function of Class $C^1$ such that $|f'(t)| \leq k < 1$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. 
>  Show that the function $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $\varphi(x,y)=(x+f(y),y+f(x))$ is a diffeomorphism.

**My Approach:** I will try to be as brief as possible about this because the calculations involved are very easy and obvious.

First I showed that the Determinant of the Jacobian Matrix of $\varphi$ is not zero for all arguments $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ which immediatly allows me to conclude that $\varphi$ is a 'local' diffeomorphism. In order to show that it is a 'global' diffeomorphism I need to verify that $\varphi$ is bijective.

**Injective:** Let $(x,y),(x',y') \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\varphi(x,y)=\varphi(x',y')$. Assume that $x \neq x'$ and $y \neq y'$. Try to raise contradiction. We have: $$x+f(y)=x'+f(y')$$
But since $x \neq x'$ the above equality can only hold if $f(y) \neq f(y')$ and it follows that $f$ is injective. But if $f$ is injective it is strictly monotone on its domain which contradicts that $|f'(t)| < 1, \ \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$

**Surjective:** Here I fail, I want to find $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for arbitrary $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\varphi(x,y)=(u,v)$ which leaves me with two equations: $$x+f(y)=u \\y+f(x)=v $$
It isn't obvious to me why I can solve for $x,y$ in the above equations. Since I only want to verify the existence of such $x,y$ (and unlikely compute them explicitly) maybe someone could help me show an approach on how to do so.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}x$ is injective, strictly monotone and the absolute value of its derivative is $\frac{1}{2} < 1$

Comment: @Giovanni thanks a lot, I thought that there might have been something that slipped my mind, I will try to make my injective 'proof' work somehow because it seems like I am on to something.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/852896/70305) there is an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prove that $\varphi$ is surjective**

Take $(u,v) \in \mathbb R^2$ and consider $\Phi : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ given by $\Phi(x,y)=(u-f(y),v-f(x))$.

For $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in \mathbb R^2$ you have $$\Vert \Phi(x_1,y_1)-\Phi(x_2,y_2) \Vert = \Vert (f(y_1)-f(y_2),f(x_1)-f(x_2)) \Vert \le k\Vert (x_1,y_1) - (x_2,y_2) \Vert$$ where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the $\mathbb R^2$ norm.

This means that $\Phi$ is a strict contraction. Hence according to Banach fixed point theorem $\Phi$ has a fixed point, which means $$\Phi(x,y)=(u-f(y),v-f(x)) =(x,y)\Leftrightarrow \varphi(x,y)=(u,v)$$

Finally $\varphi$ is surjective.